# Using qTip in Chrome Extension to show annotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, qtip

I am building a Chrome extension to annotate text on any website. So far it takes input in a basic Javascript prompt window and displays it back on `.onmouseover` in an alert box. However, I want to employ the use of the qTip2 jQuery plugin instead of using the alert box.

Here's how my manifest.json stands currently:

```
"content_scripts": [{"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
                      "js": ["content.js", "jquery-1.3.2.min.js", "jquery.qtip.min.js"],
                      "run_at": "document_start",
                      "all_frames": true
                    }],
```

Here's the snippet that takes the annotation and displays it:

```
    function surroundSelection() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";

    //prompt box to enter annotation
    var text = prompt("Enter annotation below:");

    //shows the annotated text on mouseover
    span.onmouseover=function(){
    alert(text);
}

    if (document.getSelection()) {
        var sel = document.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked through a few examples of qTip2 in action and all of them work with some HTML attribute like class or ID in the following fashion:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   // Match all link elements with href attributes within the content div
   $('#content a[href]').qtip(
   {
      content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip' // Give it some content, in this case a simple string
   });
});
```

My question is how do I get qTip to work on my annotation?

Comment: The first step whould be to put your content.js AFTER jQuery and qTip in your manifest.

Comment: Where is the `span` defined that you use in `span.onmouseover`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `span` object is a DOM element, you can probably just

```
$(span).qtip({
     "key1": value1,
     "key2": value2,
          ...
     "keyN": valueN
});
```

after `range.surroundContents(span);` instead of the `.onmouseover` lines, as long as your jQuery and qTip2 references are already valid.

You can pass DOM elements to jQuery to get a jQuery object for that element [as shown in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element). The qTip sample just wants a valid jQuery object to plug into.

Most often people do that with selectors, but there's (probably) no reason you couldn't

1. instantiate a DOM element,
2. stick it on the page,
3. get a jQuery object for it,
4. and pass that to qTip.

Comment: I have converted the span element to a jQuery object and plugged that into qTip 2. But could you be a little more clear about the `range.surroundContents(span);` and `.onmouseover` bits? Thanks!